# Creating a pdf with non selectable text using MSWord ActiveX

Tags: delphi, pdf, ms-word, activex, word-2007

I am converting doc to pdf using Word 2007+ ActiveX.

Is it possible to create the pdf from using activex by specifiying some document properties like "not allow to select text"?

Answer (score 0):

You don't specify what you are using to create the PDF with so I can only point you in the general direction. (ActiveX is generic framework, we need the specific technology/library that you are using such as Adobe Acrobat or Ghostscript or whatever.)

There are two types of passwords that you can set in a PDF, "user" and "owner". If the "user" password is set people will need to enter it before be allowed to open the document. The "owner" password (which is what you are looking for) controls advanced settings such as copying text and images, printing and editing. Whatever technology you are using you will need to set the "owner" password and set what options you want to allow. You might find these options fall under document encryption depending on the library, too.

Just a warning, Adobe Acrobat and Adobe Reader both respect the "owner" password settings but not all programs do. In fact, if you set the "owner" password from with Adobe Acrobat you will get prompted with a warning to that effect. If you are trying to stop the casual office worker from selecting your text this is usually fine but if you are storing government secrets or copyrighted works I would recommend finding another solution.

Comment: I wrote "Word 2007+ ActiveX", I mean I use OLE AUtomation of MS Word 2007 or MS Word 2010

Comment: Anyway when saving to pdf using MS word (I mean the user interface of MS WOrd) I have some options, one option is to password protect it, but I don't see the option to generate a "non selectable" document, a document where I cannot select the text, so probably also in the activex this is not doable.